# communication between user controls

Tags: winforms, user-controls

I have a windows form that has two usercontrols, UC1 and UC2. UC2 need some information about the state of UC1. One way I can think of is that UC2 has an instance of UC1 as class member and I can initialize that instance of UC1 (contained in UC2) with the one contained in form.  After that whenever UC2 need to get any info about UC1, it can just get that from its local class variables. Not sure though if its the best approach?

Comment: Not a good idea.  Why isn't this just *one* user control?  Do you actually re-use them or does this really belong in the form class?  If you have to, have the form constructor set the reference they need.

Answer (score 0):

Just create some object that has two interfaces. One to shove stuff in and one to receive stuff from. The object itself will just shove straight through. The the owner form creates an instance and assigns the injects the interfaces into UC1 and UC2.

If the owning form doesn't need to "pair" them up, then just use static instance.